# Send pre-compressed file on HTTP request

Tags: gzip, apache, static-files

I just learned about the gzip-compression features of modern browsers and webservers.
If I understood right, the server compresses on request of the browser and on the fly.

But: 
I have some static, gzip'ed json files on a webserver. I would like to simply send those, not compress them each time they are requested.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,

m

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The answer is here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/78469/apache-send-pre-packed-gziped-files

Answer (score 0):

Here is .htaccess, that works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]

AddEncoding x-gzip .gz

<FilesMatch .*\.htm.gz>
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.html.gz>
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.css.gz>
    ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.js.gz>
    ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
```